# How can I run Selenium (rspec2/capybara) tests as if though dial up or mobile connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec2

I'd like to run my test suite as if I were on a mobile or dial up connection. I'm using a rails stack with rspec2, selenium. Any advice?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815516/how-can-i-run-selenium-used-through-capybara-at-a-lower-speed

Comment: This may also help if you're running on a Linux box to simulate latency and packet loss. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614795/simulate-delayed-and-dropped-packets-on-linux

Comment: @AllanChow that sort of helps but it looks like it's not recommended on a remote machine.

Comment: Ah ok.  I've been having the browser and the test script running on the same machine.  I've had other issues that have kept me away from working on a remote selenium server.